# How to get HTML code from a website in java program?

Tags: java, html, client, client-side

I am trying to get the html code from a website from within my java project. I was able to do this however through some exploring I found out it never loads the client side of the site (not 100% sure what the difference would be), I'm not sure if the website never runs its javascript code which might add the rest of the html code that I am looking for but this is what i think is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit - Here it the code that ended up working for me:

```
public class GetHtml {

    public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public static String get() throws Exception {

        //Connect to the website
        driver.get("webiste");


        // Sleep for 5 seconds so page can load
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        }

        //Get userlist
        List<WebElement> users=driver.findElements(By.className("userlist"));

        String s = "";
        for (WebElement w : users) {
            s += (w.getText());
        }

        return s;

    }
}
```

This opens the "website" in a firefox web browser, waits for it to load, then find this html element with the class name "userlist" and returns a string with the names of all the users currently in the userlist.

Comment: Please show the code that you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is dynamically generated with javascript or another request, one approach is to use the `selenium` browser automation framework: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

A simple example to get all elements from a page:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.example.com");

List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));
```

Comment: Thanks this works for what I need although having it opening a browser is a bit annoying but it gets the job done, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org/) library fetches a URL in its HTML scraping and parsing duties.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
```